# How To Detect If Array Displays These Results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How would I detect if an array displays the following in an if statement? (I tried NULL and it didn't work)...

When I NSLog the description of the array, this is what returns:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [manager purDesc]description]);

2011-08-30 13:43:20.227 PROJECT[2921:f503] manager purDesc Dump:(
        {
        amt = "\n      ";
        desc = "\n      ";
    }
)
```

I need to say "If `[manager purDesc]` looks like that, display a `UIAlertView`".

*Sorry everyone, I feel like I'm having trouble getting my point across this morning. If you don't understand, please comment with your question and I'll try to explain better.*

Comment: You're trying to determine if the fields in `purDesc` contain only whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your structure seems to be a dictionary inside an array.  Not sure how that all stacks up.  To see if all items in a dictionary are only whitespace.

```
BOOL empty = YES;
NSCharacterSet* wp = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
for(NSString* key in dict)
{
    NSString* val = [dict objectForKey: key];
    // trim white space and check length
    if([[val stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: wp]length])
    {
        empty = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```

the array version is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: What does the "for(NSString* key in dict)" mean here? key in dict?

Comment: Modern for loop iterating on dictionary.  Works same as NSString* key; NSArray* keys = [dict allKeys]; int i; for(key=[allKeys objectAtIndex:(i=0); i < [allKeys count]; key=[allKeys objectAtIndex: i++])

Answer (score 0):

If those fields are `NSString`, you might want to check out [`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a).

```
NSString* trimmedAmount = [amt stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove whitespace and returns by using the NSString method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: along with the static set whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet.

However, based on the output of [purDesc description], it looks like you may have an NSDictionary, not an array.

Comment: You are correct. purDesc is an array of dictionarys. In that description, it holds one dictionary of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the actual elements of the array? somehting like

[manager objecAtIndex:0] = nil

Comment: That snippet is a) a syntax error, and b) wouldn't tell you if a string was only whitespace, but if it was not an object at all.